# Dualities involving Supersymmetric QED in $3+1$d

Tags: gauge-theory, supersymmetry, duality

Most of the supersymmetric dualities in $3+1$d involve only non-Abelian gauge theories, like $SU(N)$ $\mathcal{N}=1$ SQCD, etc. Are there examples of dualities which involve supersymmetric QED (i.e. with matter) in $3+1$d?

Comment: See for example of S-duality http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9505186.